# combine edit address form billing and shipping in my-address.php woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I want to display edit billing form and edit shipping form together. actually I want remove edit button and display directly forms in "my-account/edit-address/" address.
is it possible ?

I created forms in my-address file but it did not work and when you submit form it redirected billing form